# Why is no data being stored in my array?

Tags: c#, arrays

So i have an array that will store strings. Im getting those strings from a MySQL reader.

logIn.cs

```
sessionData userSession = new sessionData();
                    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
                    {
                        userSession.UserData[i] = reader.GetString(i);
                    }
```

This is where i try to assign the strings to the array.

The array is located in another file called sessionData and is declared like this:

sessionData.cs

```
class sessionData
{
    public string[] UserData = new string[7];


}
```

I then try to access it like so:

landingPage.cs

```
  public landingPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        sessionData userData = new sessionData();

        welcomeBox.Text = "Hi, " + userData.UserData[1] + ".";

    }
```

It should show the account name but instead all array elements are null?

Why wont the data get stored?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well for one, it appears you are assigning to a variable named `userSession` and reading from one named `userData`.

Comment: @Alex Sorry forgot to paste in a vital part.

Comment: `new sessionData()` .. so, this is a *newly* created object containing a *newly* created array .. that has not had any elements assigned.

Comment: Please post some actual code. There cannot be something like `public landingPage()`, i.e. a method without a return type. This would never compile. When posting code with a question, it is encouraged to post a minimal code sample with which the problem can be reproduced. Perhaps you intended for `userData` to be a member variable.

Comment: @Alex That is all thats in the landingPage.cs other than using statements.

Comment: @Alex `class landingPage { public landingPage() { /* hi! */ } }` - it could be a constructor.. :D

Comment: I would say, put a breakpoint and check the return value of getString ()

Comment: @user2864740 Im still fairly new. How do i change the values of the array and access them from another file if the way ive done it is wrong?

Comment: @user2864740, Agreed, if this is the constructor. Sorry Alana.

Comment: @AlanaStephens The (well, "a") problem is not using the *same* array (because of not using the *same* containing object). This code is well, uhm, hard to follow the usage. Where is the code that contains `reader.GetString(i)` located? A simple/clean approach (for a single usage) would be to have something like `var userData = LoadUserData(); welcomeBox.Text = ..`, where `LoadUserData` returns the created object, with the data loaded in the array. Basically, have the values 'flow through' the program when possible.

Comment: @user2864740 I edited the OP to show that everything is in 3 completely different files. Also could you please give me a more thorough explanation please as i dont quiet get it.

Comment: @user2864740 Well coming from other languages this way did work. Im not entirely used to OOP in C# yet, Still learning.

Comment: you need to persist your session data. every time you do `sessionData <something> = new sessionData()` you are creating a new instance which is initialised to an empty array, that's why it appears empty in your landingpage. what sort of app is this? mvc? forms? console?

Comment: @AlanaStephens My mistake, I thought it was a Webforms application. It is apparently a Winforms application (for use of `InitializeComponent()`). In any case, back to original problem: just as in X (C++, Ruby, Python, JavaScript, etc), if you create *two* objects you have *two* separate objects. You need to access the *same* object. I recommend making a function build and return the object (and avoid global state, if possible) but you can use member variables (including static members that can act like 'global' variables) to share the *same* object. These work as the X counterparts do.

Comment: @pala_ its a forms app, But thank you anyways.

Comment: It's largely frowned upon but you might want to look at the 'singleton' design pattern, or look at a simple static class to hold the data.